# Model doesn't bind in POST controller method .Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, post, axios, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model:

```
    public class CompanyFooterUpdateModel
    {
        public CompanyFooterUpdateModel(){}
        public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string FooterHtml { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveFooter([FromBody] CompanyFooterUpdateModel model)
    {
       //.... do something in Company controller
    }
```

View, with axios post:

```
function SaveCompanyFooter() {
    axios.post('@Url.Action("SaveFooter", "Company")',
        {
            model: {
                FooterHtml: window.HtmlEditor.getData(),
                CompanyId: "@Model.CompanyId"
            }
        }
    ).then(response => {
        // .... do something
    });
}
```

Then, I tried everything, [FromBody], anything else, nothing...
Please explain, what I did wrong?

**UPD1:**
so I have tried something like this too:

```
axios.post('@Url.Action("SaveFooter", "Company")',
    {
        "FooterHtml": window.HtmlEditor.getData(),
        "CompanyId": "@Model.CompanyId"
    }
)
```

and

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> SaveFooter(Guid CompanyId, string FooterHtml)...
```

**UPD2:**
[Controller action screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8hFQ.png)

[JS in View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5OPx.png)

Comment: What is them problem? Does it hit a controller?  Is controller action input parameter is empty?

Comment: @Serge in HttpContext.Request...Body I can see with debugger my POST body data. But, for some reason, Model is empty (initialized with defaul values)

Comment: But  it hits an action?

Comment: @Serge yes, it hits an Action

Comment: Mostly a guess, but try removing the `model` property from the JavaScript object and just making that property value the whole object.

Comment: @David I have tried this, same issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove " from javascript

```
axios.post('@Url.Action("SaveFooter", "Company")',
    {
        FooterHtml: window.HtmlEditor.getData(),
        CompanyId: "@Model.CompanyId"
    }
)
```

or try to add json header

```
axios.post('@Url.Action("SaveFooter", "Company")',
    {
        FooterHtml: window.HtmlEditor.getData(),
        CompanyId: "@Model.CompanyId"
    }
),
 {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
  .then((response) => {
.....
```

and use this action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveFooter([FromBody] CompanyFooterUpdateModel model)
    {
       //.... do something in Company controller
    }
```

Comment: Please check UPD2

Comment: Will try tomorrow :) thank you

Comment: So, your answer helps me. Thank you. Strange, that project is a migration from .net mvc Framework to .net core 5 mvc. And with "old version" it works just correct. Strange.

Comment: You are welcome!